# how to group table data using two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, vb6

I have table with three columns i.e. description, amount, month.
I want to group description in month from January to December.

I have tried:

```
insert into summary(transdate,particulars,amount_cr) select month,description,sum(amount) from petty_cash_logs group by month,description
```

but it is not summing the description amount it is only listing them.

Comment: I suggest you add `sql` and `mysql` tags to get more people to see your question.

Comment: This mysql code should work as required. Please add sample data which proves it does not.